# Rails - update multiple resource entries with one link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, nested-attributes, forms

I have a table of forms

```
<% @group.lessons.each do |lesson| %>
  <%= form_for [@group, lesson] do |f| %>
    <tr id='<%= lesson.id%>' >
      <td><%= f.text_field :time %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :day %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :subject %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :teacher %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :room %></td>
      <td><%= f.submit 'Update'%></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', [lesson.group, lesson], method: :delete%></td>
    </tr>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Each form updates an entry when the "update" button is clicked. But when you edit two entries and update only one, the info you edited in the other one is gone.

I want to have a button to update each entry in the table. How do I do this?

Comment: why you don't just use  nested attributes for lessons?

Comment: Please reply if you have a better general solution. I don't understand what you are asking about.

Comment: Assuming Group and Lesson are two models, are they associated in any way?

Comment: @Charles lessons belong to group, group has many lessons.

Comment: This is a solution for nested attributes

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:**

First in model:

```
class Group < AR::Base # possibly you'r using ActiveRecord

  attr_accessible :lessons_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lessons, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :lessons

end
```

and then in your view: # e.g. views/groups/_form.html.erb

```
<table>
    <%= form_for @group do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>
      <%= f.fields_for :lessons do |lesson_form| %>
        <%= render "lessons/lesson", :f => lesson_form%>
      <% end %>
     <tr><td><%= f.submit 'Update'%></td></tr>
   <% end %>
</table>
```

and in views/lessons/_lesson.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td>  
   <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
    <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Lesson" %>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But what's the 'raw' way to do it? I mean without gems. I want to know for the learning sake

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of an html issue than a rails issue. You simply can't submit more than one form using plain html. That's why you're losing one form when you submit the other.

What you could do however is update multiple lessons that belong to the same group using nested attributes. Here are some resources for that:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: Agreed.  This questions is an attempt to learn a pattern for form-field-submission, not Rails functionality.